# vue: change the table header name depending on checkbox selected

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have checkboxes and I need to change the Header on my table depending on
the checkbox selected.

From `<th>Default</th>`...

- If checkbox1 is selected then the header will be change to
  "CheckBox1".
- If checkbox2 is selected then the header will be change to
  "CheckBox2".
- If checkbox3 is selected then the header will be change to
  "CheckBox3".
- If checkbox4 is selected then the header will be change to
  "CheckBox4".
- If two or more checkbox is selected "Default" is displayed.
- If none checkbox is selected or empty, "Default" is also displayed in
  the table header.

```
<input name="cb1" type="checkbox" value="cb1"> CheckBox1
<input name="cb2" type="checkbox" value="cb2"> CheckBox2
<input name="cb3" type="checkbox" value="cb3"> CheckBox3
<input name="cb4" type="checkbox" value="cb4"> CheckBox4

<br>
<br>
<table width="30%"  border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Row</th>
    <th>Default</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am using vue and typescript and currently new to it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should consider using `v-model` for each checkBox instead of the `value` property ([documentation here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html))

---

You can use the `computed` property to computed the title of your page into a function ([documentation here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html))

---

Working example using classic JS

```js
new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data() {
        return {
          cb1: false,
          cb2: false,
          cb3: false,
          cb4: false,
        }
      },

      computed: {
        tableTitle() {
          //get the number of checkbox checked
          const nbCheckBox = [this.cb1, this.cb2, this.cb3, this.cb4].reduce((total, current) => total + (current ? 1 : 0), 0)              

          if (nbCheckBox === 1) {
            if (this.cb1) return 'CheckBox1'
            else if (this.cb2) return 'CheckBox2'
            else if (this.cb3) return 'CheckBox3'
            else if (this.cb4) return 'CheckBox4'
          } else return 'Default'
        }
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <input name="cb1" type="checkbox" v-model="cb1"> CheckBox1
  <input name="cb2" type="checkbox" v-model="cb2"> CheckBox2
  <input name="cb3" type="checkbox" v-model="cb3"> CheckBox3
  <input name="cb4" type="checkbox" v-model="cb4"> CheckBox4

  <br>
  <br>
  <table width="30%" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>{{ tableTitle }}</th>
      <th>Default</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

For TS, you can specify the return type of the computed value like

```js
computed: {
        tableTitle(): string {
          ....
        }
```

Comment: Glad to help, do not hesitate to mark my answer if it's the right solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `v-model` on the checkboxes.

Use something like this for the header:

```js
boxes.filter(b => b.selected).length === 1 ? boxes.find(b => 
 b.selected).name : "Default"
```

[See this playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHNjcmlwdCBzZXR1cD5cbmltcG9ydCB7IHJlZiB9IGZyb20gJ3Z1ZSdcbmNvbnN0IGJveGVzID0gcmVmKFtcbiAgeyBuYW1lOiBcIkNoZWNrQm94MVwiLCBzZWxlY3RlZDogZmFsc2UgfSxcbiAgeyBuYW1lOiBcIkNoZWNrQm94MlwiLCBzZWxlY3RlZDogZmFsc2UgfSxcbiAgeyBuYW1lOiBcIkNoZWNrQm94M1wiLCBzZWxlY3RlZDogdHJ1ZSB9LFxuICB7IG5hbWU6IFwiQ2hlY2tCb3g0XCIsIHNlbGVjdGVkOiBmYWxzZSB9XG5dKVxuPC9zY3JpcHQ+XG5cbjx0ZW1wbGF0ZT5cbiAgPHRlbXBsYXRlIHYtZm9yPVwiYm94IGluIGJveGVzXCIgOmtleT1cImJveC5uYW1lXCI+XG4gICAgPHA+XG4gICAgICA8bGFiZWw+XG4gICAgICAgIHt7Ym94Lm5hbWV9fVxuICAgICAgICA8aW5wdXQgdHlwZT1cImNoZWNrYm94XCIgdi1tb2RlbD1cImJveC5zZWxlY3RlZFwiPlxuICAgICAgPC9sYWJlbD5cbiAgICA8L3A+XG4gIDwvdGVtcGxhdGU+XG4gIDxicj5cbiAgPHRhYmxlIHdpZHRoPVwiMzAlXCIgIGJvcmRlcj1cIjFcIj5cbiAgICA8dHI+XG4gICAgICA8dGg+Um93PC90aD5cbiAgICAgIDx0aD57eyBib3hlcy5maWx0ZXIoYiA9PiBiLnNlbGVjdGVkKS5sZW5ndGggPT09IDEgPyBib3hlcy5maW5kKGIgPT4gYi5zZWxlY3RlZCkubmFtZSA6IFwiRGVmYXVsdFwiIH19PC90aD5cbiAgICA8L3RyPlxuICAgIDx0cj5cbiAgICAgIDx0ZD4mbmJzcDs8L3RkPlxuICAgICAgPHRkPiZuYnNwOzwvdGQ+XG4gICAgPC90cj5cbiAgPC90YWJsZT5cbjwvdGVtcGxhdGU+IiwiaW1wb3J0LW1hcC5qc29uIjoie1xuICBcImltcG9ydHNcIjoge1xuICAgIFwidnVlXCI6IFwiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZmMudnVlanMub3JnL3Z1ZS5ydW50aW1lLmVzbS1icm93c2VyLmpzXCJcbiAgfVxufSJ9)

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const boxes = ref([
  { name: "CheckBox1", selected: false },
  { name: "CheckBox2", selected: false },
  { name: "CheckBox3", selected: true },
  { name: "CheckBox4", selected: false }
])
</script>

<template>
  <template v-for="box in boxes" :key="box.name">
    <p>
      <label>
        {{box.name}}
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="box.selected">
      </label>
    </p>
  </template>
  <br>
  <table width="30%"  border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Row</th>
      <th>{{ boxes.filter(b => b.selected).length === 1 ? boxes.find(b => b.selected).name : "Default" }}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</template>
```